# Does the state of Colorado require two signatures on application to disclose information to the social security administration (SSA)?

Tags: colorado, social-security, social-security-card

I was looking at a form **SSE-827-F3** (03-2020)

---

Form form **SSE-827-F3** states that a "parent, guardian, or personal representative must sign the form if two signatures are required by State law".

---

I do not know all of the laws in the state laws for Colorado.

---

Does the state of Colorado require two signatures on application to disclose information to the social security administration (SSA)?

Comment: Would this be in the context of a Social Security Disability benefits application?